# Изменение класса у div'a

Tags: классы, php, html

Здравствуй, ХешКод! Сейчас столкнулся с проблемой, и не знаю как её решить, помогите пожалуйста. У меня есть таблица с сообщениями, в этой таблице есть поле

```
unread
```

Которое отвечает за то прочитал пользователь письмо, или нет. Далее когда в цикле вывожу эти письма, все они имеют класс unread, но после нажатия на кнопку "Прочитано", класс должен сменится на read, но беда в том, что когда я это делаю, то класс меняется у **всех** сообщений, а не только у кого в котором была нажата кнопка. Подскажите как, сделать так чтобы при нажатии на сообщение, только у **него одного** менялся класс?

P.S Использую библиотеку Jquery последнюю версию.

P.P.S Пример кода.

```
    <?php
if($data->unread == 0){
    echo '<div class="unread" style = "border: 2px solid red;">';
}else{
    echo '<div class="read">';
}
?>

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('user_from')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->user_from).' ('.date("m.d.Y в G:m", CHtml::encode($data->date)).')'; ?>
    <br />

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('title')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->title); ?>
    <br />

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('body')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->body); ?>
    <br />

    <?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>
        <div class = "row submit">
        <?php echo Chtml::hiddenField('id_hidden', $data->id); ?>

        <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Прочитано', '', array(
            'type'=>'POST',
            'update'=>'#output',
            'success'=>'js:function(){
                $(".view").removeClass("view").addClass("view2");
            }',
        )); ?>
        </div>
    <?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
</div>
```

На выходе даёт такой html

```
<div class="unread" style = "border: 2px solid red;">
    <b>От кого:</b>
    admin (08.29.2013 в 11:08)    <br />

    <b>Тема:</b>
    Hello    <br />

    <b>Сообщение:</b>
    fnweiufne    <br />

    <form action="/message/index" method="post">        <div class = "row submit">
        <input type="hidden" value="8" name="id_hidden" id="id_hidden" />
        <input type="submit" name="yt1" value="Прочитано" id="yt1" />       </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: пример кода html в студию

Comment: код покажи у таблицы... 

Подозреваю что можно выйти на родителя у кнопки (это будет td) и еще раз на родителя (это будет tr) и там начать искать по классу, тогда найдет классы в этом tr-е.

Но к сожалению как у вас выглядит таблица не ясно...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
      <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Прочитано', '', array(
            'type'=>'POST',
            'update'=>'#output',
            'success'=>'js:function(){
                $(this).closest("div").removeClass("unread").addClass("read");
            }',
        )); ?>
```

Как то так

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, однако этот код не работает( Класс не меняется.

Comment: к чему там вообще форма, если у вас ajax запрос? Вообще в Yii писать js в php настоящее зло, ИМХО конечно же.
Мой совет, уберите форму. Сделайте простую ссылку, в href укажите урл. id как и есть сейчас пусть будет в hidden поле. и опишите ajax запрос сами. А не работает потому что я еще один div провтыкал, который внутри формы находится. Попробуйте так 
    $(this).parent("div.unread").removeClass("unread").addClass("read");

Comment: Не работает( А почему плохо писать внутри Yii, js? Так описано в документации...

Comment: внутри yii можно и нужно. Внутри php не очень хорошо его писать. eval по сути, лишние операции, пусть js будет в js, это логично. По поводу не работает, если до утра не разберетесь, то завтра фиддл набросаю, скину ссыль

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо! :-)

Comment: как и обещал фиддл - http://jsfiddle.net/Barton89/Es3dT/